# What is the best way to go about modeling something like Digg?

Tags: python, algorithm, matlab, statistics, scipy

I'm creating a news platform identical to Digg. How would I model its voting mechanism algorithm?  I'm looking for a logical/mathematical approach.

Comment: You should probably first get a lawyer to handle the inevitable copyright lawsuit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://reddit.com is a better version of the now abandoned Digg and guess what, reddit's code and ranking mechanism is open source.

Find the developer page for reddit [here](http://code.reddit.com/).

[How Reddit ranking algorithms work (amix.dk)](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19588)